# Publish .jsp with scriptlet on AWS Beanstalk Environment

Tags: jsp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, publishing, scriptlet

I want to publish my Dynamic Web Project on the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment. I did a lot of try and error and found out that the reason for my problems is the Scriptlet below. As soon as i delete it, my website works. 
(Perhaps interesting: I can publish my project on a tomcat localhost server WITH the scriptlet without problems.

Scriptlet:

```
<%
Twitter_String TS = new Twitter_String();
String TwitterString = TS.Twitter_Stringbuilder();
%>
  var heatmapdata = [<%=TwitterString%>];
```

I really looked up everything and can't find out why the scriptlet doesn't work on the beanstalk environment but on the tomcat localhost server. My Beanstalk environment runs with "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.0 running Tomcat 7 Java 7". My Tomcat localhost also with version 7. Please help me.

I cant post a image of my project structure yet. But here is my code. I also have included all necessary .jars in the WEB-INF lib folder.

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ page import="AP.Twitter.Twitter_String"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Heatmaps</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #panel {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        left: 25%;
        padding: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        z-index: 5;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button>
      <button onclick="changeGradient()">Change gradient</button>
      <button onclick="changeRadius()">Change radius</button>
      <button onclick="changeOpacity()">Change opacity</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>


var map, heatmap;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });


  <%
Twitter_String TS = new Twitter_String();
String TwitterString = TS.Twitter_Stringbuilder();
%>
  var heatmapdata = [<%=TwitterString%>];


  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: heatmapdata,
    map: map
  });
}

function toggleHeatmap() {
  heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
}

function changeGradient() {
  var gradient = [
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
    'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
    'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
    'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
  ];
  heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
}

function changeRadius() {
  heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 50);
}

function changeOpacity() {
  heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

DataBaseConnect,java

```
package AP.Twitter;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public abstract class DataBaseConnect {

    protected static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://*****",
                "postgres", "*****");
    }
}
```

Twitter_String.java

```
package AP.Twitter;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;



public class Twitter_String extends DataBaseConnect{

        public String Twitter_Stringbuilder() throws SQLException{

        String query = new StringBuilder().append("SELECT * from tswholeworld").toString();
        Connection con = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String finalString;


        try {
            while(rs.next()) {
                String lat = rs.getString(3);
                String lon = rs.getString(4);

                stringBuilder.append("new google.maps.LatLng("+lat+", "+lon+"), ");


            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        finalString = stringBuilder.toString();
        return finalString;


}
}
```